# Converting string to valid wordpress url in python 3 to be used by requests library

Tags: python, wordpress, python-3.x, url, python-requests

Given a string  `https://websiteurl/path/photo's url.jpeg`

How to converted it to legal url `https://websiteurl/path/photos-url.jpeg` from Wordpress point of view using python3.5. This url is going to be used by sending post request with json where *src* will be key and *value* the above legal url.

When the photo was uploaded url `https://websiteurl/path/photos-url.jpeg`  was given to it. (*'* removed and space converted to *-* )

The only way i see is using `"https://websiteurl/path/photo's url.jpeg".replace(\',"").replace(" ","-")`.

Is there any generic pythonic way?

Comment: Maybe use `re.sub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use re.sub and str.replace. Example:

```
import re

special_chars = ["?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "'", "\"", "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`", "!", "{", "}", "%", "+"]
uri = "photo's url.jpeg"

#use str.replace
for i in special_chars:
    uri = uri.replace(i, "")

#or re.sub
#uri = re.sub("\?|\[|\]|/|\\|\=|<|>|:|;|,|'|\"|\&|\$|#|\*|\(|\)|~|`|!|\{|\}|%|\+", "", uri)

uri = re.sub("\s+", "-", uri)
print(uri)
```

This will change `photo's url.jpeg` into `photos-url.jpeg`.
Take a look at how wordpress is doing it in php here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1761